# Mongodb the time series collection is slower than a normal collection when dealing with iot data

Tags: mongodb, time-series, iot

I stored some iot data in a normal collection and a time series collection, respectively.

The schema for the normal collection:

```js
const TcpDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  src_ip: String,
  dst_ip: String,
  dst_mac: String,
  src_mac: String,
  dst_port: String,
  src_port: String,
  packet_size: String,
  protocols: Array,
  timestamp: {type: Number, required: true},
}, {
  autoIndex: false,
})
```

The schema for the time series collection:

```js
const TimeTcpDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp: Date,
  metadata: {
    src_ip: String,
    dst_ip: String,
    dst_mac: String,
    src_mac: String,
    dst_port: String,
    src_port: String,
    protocols: Array,
  },
  packet_size: String,
}, {
  timeseries: {
    timeField: 'timestamp',
    metaField: 'metadata',
  },
})
```

They both have an index on 'timestamp'.

I made a query like this in both collections

```sql
{
    $match:
      {
        timestamp: {
          $gte: <start>,
          $lte: <end>,
        },
      },
  },
```

The result from the normal collection:
[explain plan (normal collection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bnM9.png)

The result from the time series collection:
[explain plan (time series collection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v0Oc.png)

The time series collection spent more time on this query. How come?

The db version is 6.0.4

Comment: The explain plan links go to truncated images. Please provide the expanded text of each to this question

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors